systemctl не запускается gdm (Ubuntu 24.04.1)
При вводе команды sudo systemctl enable gdm происходит ошибка:

The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=,
UpheldBy=, Also=, or Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and
DefaultInstance= for template units). This means they are not meant to
be enabled or disabled using systemctl.   Possible reasons for having
these kinds of units are: • A unit may be statically enabled by being
symlinked from another unit's   .wants/, .requires/, or .upholds/
directory. • A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other
unit which has   a requirement dependency on it. • A unit may be
started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,   D-Bus,
udev, scripted systemctl call, ...). • In case of template units, the
unit is meant to be enabled with some   instance name specified.

и каждый раз система запускается без gdm.

В общем насколько я смог разобраться, команда sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 должна (пере)создать юнит /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service который в свою очередь будет подтягиваться через Wants юнитом graphical.target, а пытаться редактировать gdm.service напрямую не надо

sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
reboot

Так делать нельзя, слетит при ближайшем обновлении

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как написать хороший ответ => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer //пожалуйста, ответьте на комментарий  andreymal, если вы считаете, что ваше решение решит вопрос ТС. Благодарю.
